# Which iOS should I run on my iPhone?

Tags: iphone

Which iOS 8 should I run on my 4S?
It's currently running iOS 8.1
I really don't want to update, but my stop button doesn't work and I don't have any cam tweaks, and the phone lags on opening, I can't buy a new phone anytime soon

Answer (score 6):

With an iDevice you always have 2 choices

- Stay with the iOS you have

or

- Update to the latest available [or supported, for end-of-life devices] iOS.

There is no 3rd choice.

Any bugs in the early releases of any 'whole number' iOS are usually fixed over the next few months, so it is usually better to be on the latest version.